# jetbrain products: replace in selection

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide

I used Eclipse and there it was possible to select a text and replace text only in the selection. Is it possible in Android Studio for example too?

Picture from Notepad++ *(look beyond the "replace with")*

[image: Picture from Notepad++]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Nearly exactly as already described. Select a text, press ctrl-R(eplace) or (F)ind. 
You'll get a additional bar where "In Selection" is already checked.

Comment: in your editor pane, in case of (R) a 2 line bar where you enter search phrase and replacement, checkbox far to the right.